# Java Spring Injection String

Tags: java, spring

How do I inject a String into a class. I Have seen plenty of examples of how to inject a class but can't find any for a String.

Comment: `private static final String CONSTANT_STRING = "Some Value";`.  Or perhaps more seriously, if you can inject a class, then why not implement a minimal class that has a method that returns the String you want to inject, and then inject that class instead of the String itself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to know how this is done through a construct arg or setter method.

Answer (score 3):

An example: If your field is called "name" and your class is called "Person" you can use setter injection like this:

```
<bean id="personBean" class="example.Person">
    <property name="name" value="Paul" />
</bean>
```

It should be as simple as that. You will obviously need setter methods in your Person class for name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does there need to be any annotation such as @Autowire

Comment: No @Autowire does something slightly different. Here we are just creating a simple bean and setting the fields on it.

Comment: +1, this should do the trick.  However, can you specify a version that does the same thing using only annotations?  Configuring Spring (or anything else tightly-coupled to source-code) using XML is an atrocity.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't want to do this with annotations. What if I want to have 5 Person objects all with different names?

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding of spring, if I created a class called People, the People class created an instance of Person, will the String name value be automatically set through use of the above code?

Comment: You would need to define a bean called People like this `<bean id="peopleBean" class="example.People">` then use setter injection again to insert the personBean into the People bean (You would probably have a list of person in this instance). Then the answer to your question would be yes, as that "Person" would be the instance created by the above code, his name value would be maintained. Hope that helps

Comment: @cowls - "The only reasonable numbers are zero, one, and infinity".  If you want to have more than one `Person` object, then you should prefer an approach that easily allows you to set up an arbitrary number of instances.  In such a case, I think calling the setter at runtime would make a lot more sense than trying to preconfigure all the possible names in XML.  As a counter-example, what if I want to change `Person` into an abstract class and derive things like `Manager` and `Employee` from it, and I forget to update the XML file when doing so?

Comment: @aroth A fair argument, it's true there's added maintenance with the external configuration file and you're right that allowing an arbitrary number of people at runtime would be much more ideal. I guess it's a matter of weighing up what is required before deciding which way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Let Spring know where to find your properties file (in this case myProperties.properties):

```
    <!-- Spring will replace ${} keys with values from the file used by the propertyConfigurer   -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="location" value="classpath:myProperties.properties"/>
    </bean>
```

In your class, you can inject like this:

```
@Value("${web.theme}")
private String theme;
```

In this case, the property defined bye "web.theme" in myProperties.properties will be injected into the "theme" member variable. But you can also inject in the constructor or setter as well.

If you don't want to use annotations, you can use it in your xml file as well.

Comment: I think this is the right answer because the question is about how to inject a String into an object, not a bean.